# How to Turn Off Google Security Alert for My Unverified Google App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

How do I turn off the security alert from Google when someone uses the Google App Script I developed?

The app access our information, so every time someone uses it we get an email with subject line "Security Alert" and the body of the emails just says the app was granted access to the account.

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/3230421?hl=en